# grep: Unknown option -C

Tags: windows, grep

I want grep to print 2 lines before and after the matching line.
I am using GnuWin32 grep(2.5.4). But it is showing error as follows:

```
grep: Unknown option -C
Usage:  grep [-clqinsvxEF] [-bI] [-e pattern] [-f patternfile] [pattern] [file   ...]
```

As per my understanding from the error, the -C option is not supported by GnuWin32.

So my doubt is The GnuWin32 grep will not support -C option or any updated version is there for GnuWin32 grep which would support -C option....

Comment: are you able to print a help page similar to what `grep --help` would do on a linux system?

Comment: @ user5631389: When I just tried -C option with grep, it is working now. And if I run grep --help command , it is showing more options than before.  I don't know what magic has been worked during this time. Anyways, many more thanks